# Aumentar um mapa de paths com d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

estou criando um mapa de um estado usando o D3.js o o codigo pega os dados de um arquivo GeoJson consigo mostrar o mapa da tela mas com tamanho bem pequeno. com faço para aumentar o tamanho desse mapa.Não consigo utilizar as funções .scale() e .translate([]) para mudar o tamanho do mapa.
o arquivo Geojson seguem nesse [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbrugz/geodata-br/master/geojson/geojs-15-mun.json) 
o codigo segue abaixo.

teste

```
</head>
<body>

    <script>

       var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg").style("background-color","#ccc")
            .attr("width", 700)
            .attr("height", 700)


        d3.json("geojs-15-mun.json",function(data){

           var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
                   .data(data.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("g")

           var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

           var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

           var areas = group.append("path")
                   .attr("d",path)
                   .attr("class","area")
                   .attr("fill","steelblue");




        });


    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Consegue colocar o código mais completo para eu poder testar?

Comment: o arquivo completo está pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239598/89191 funciona no firefox. Apenas o GeoJson está no link da pergunta.estou usando o d3.v3